# How to use native ios code with cordova?

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-plugins

I have native ios code project , I can run it fine without any problem , my aim is to use some classes in that project with cordova project .

I have create cordova project and copied the classes from native  ios code to my cordova projoct but I get errors , also I have copying cordova classes .. lib .. etc to the native ios project , also I get errors , how I can run ios native project with cordova ?

Comment: you can create plugins that use native code https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/hybrid/plugins/index.html

Comment: Hello Thank u for answer

Comment: I have create plugin , but the native  code gave me error , its collection of classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a cordova plugin that use native classes, basically is a JavaScript Interface that call native code methods.

If you have more that one class, all your classes can be included in `plugin.xml` under `<platform name="ios">` tag. In this way you can use all functions that you want.

The only way to create a plugin is following the official guide. Read this documents:

Cordova plugin development guide: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.4.0/guide/hybrid/plugins/index.html

iOS plugin development guide: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.4.0/guide/platforms/ios/plugin.html